# Varaha Avatara - reference in Taittirya recensions

Tags: vedas, brahmanas, varaha

If any one knows of references to Sri Varaha Avatara of Lord Sriman Narayana in Taittiriya Samhita / Brahmana / Arankaya, I request you to kindly post them here.

If there are references in other parts of the Vedas (Satapata Brahmana and others) I would be interested in those references as well.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mahanarayana Upanishad](http://srivaishnavism.redzambala.com/upanishad/maha-narayana-upanishad-with-commentaries-i-34-53.html), a part of taittiriya arankya describes about it.

> bhūmirdhenurdharaṇī lokadhāriṇī .
>   uddhṛtāsi varāheṇa kṛṣṇena śatabāhunā .. 38..
>
> 38. The earth is the giver of happiness like the milk cow, the sustainer of life and support for all living beings. (Represented as such the earth is **addressed:)Thou wert raised up by Kṛṣṇa in His incarnation of the boar having hundred hands.**

[Taittiriya Samhita Kanda 7](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv07.htm)

> This was in the beginning the waters, the ocean. In it Prajapati becoming the wind moved. He saw her, and becoming a boar he seized her. Her, becoming Viçvakarma, he wiped. She extended, she became the earth, and hence the earth is called the earth (lit. 'the extended'). In her Prajapati made effort. He produced the gods, Vasus, Rudras, and Adityas.

[Taittiriya Samhita Kanda 6](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv06.htm)

> Now a boar, stealer of the good, keeps the wealth of the Asuras which is to be won beyond the seven hills. Him smite, if thou art he who smites in the stronghold. He [Indra] plucked out a bunch of Darbha grass, pierced the seven hills, and smote him. He said, 'Thou art called he who brings from the stronghold; bring him.' So the sacrifice bore off the sacrifice for them; in that they won the wealth of the Asuras which was to be won (védyam), that alone is the reason why the Vedi is so called. The Asuras indeed at first owned the earth, the gods had so much as one seated can espy.

Answer (score 3):

In the Taittirtya Brahmana ([1.1.3.5](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D_(%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A0%E0%A4%83))), [Prajapati is stated](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/67726/11/11_chapter%203.pdf) to have assumed the form of a Boar, who lifted up the earth which remained plunged in the water (p.49).

> प्रजापतिः प्रजा असृजत । तासाम् अन्नम् उपाक्षीयत । ताभ्यः सूदम् उप
>   प्राभिनत् । ततो वै तासाम् अन्नं न_अक्षीयत । यस्य सूदः संभारो भवति ।
>   नास्य गृहे ऽन्नं क्षीयते । आपो वा इदम् अग्रे सलिलम् आसीत् । तेन
>   प्रजापतिर् अश्राम्यत् ।
>
> prajapatih  praja  asrjata/  tasamannamupakslyata/ 
>   tabhyassudamupaprabhinat/ tato vai tasamannam nakslyata/yasya
>   sudassambharo bhavati/nasya grhe’nnarfi ksiyate/ apo va idamagre
>   salilam aslt/ tena prajapatir-asramyata/